# Scipy optimisation routines only finding one answer

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given this function:

```
def f(x):
    return (1-x**2)**m * ((1-x)/2)**n
```

where `m` and `n` are constants, let's say both 0.5 for the sake of an example.

I'm trying to use functions from `scipy.optimize` to solve for `x` given a value of `y`.  I'm only interested in `x`values from -1 to 1.  Plotting the function with

```
x = numpy.arange(0, 1, 0,1)
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, f(x))
```

shows that the function is a kind of distorted parabola covering the range about 0 to 0.65.  So lets try solving it for y = 0.3:

```
def f(x):
    return (1 - x**2)**m * ((1-x)/2)**n - 0.3
print(scipy.optimize.newton_krylov(f, 0.5))
0.6718791645800665
```

This looks about right for one of the possible solutions.  But there are two.  The second should be around -0.9.  Try what I might for an initial guess, I can't get it to find this second solution.  The Newton-Krylov method gives no convergence at all for `xin < 0` but none of the solvers can find this second solution.

Am I missing something?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The method converges at least for x=-0.9:

```
scipy.optimize.newton_krylov(f, -0.9)
#array(-0.9527983).
```

It diverges for x approximately in [-0.85...0.06].

Answer (score 0):

This is because, [newton_krylov](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton_krylov.html) uses the Jacobian of the function. This makes it a gradient decent method consequently your solutions always converge to a local minima. Furthermore, because your function is *parabolic* you have a very interesting option!

The first is to find the maxima of `f(x)` and split your search domain into to. Next you can make an initial guess in each domain and solve with `newton_krylov`.

```
def f(x):
    # Here is our function
    return (1-x**2)**m * ((1-x)/2)**n


def minf(x):
    # Here is where we find an optima and split the domain
    return -f(x)


def fy(x):
    # This is where you want your y value target defined
    return abs(f(x) - .3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = numpy.arange(-1., 1., 1e-3, dtype=float)
    # pyplot.plot(x, f(x))
    # pyplot.show()

    minx = minimize(minf, 0.0)['x']

    # Make an initial guess in each domain
    a1 = minx - 1.6 * minx
    a2 = minx + 1.6 * minx

    print(newton_krylov(fy, a1))
    print(newton_krylov(fy, a2))
```

The output then is:

```
[0.67187916]
[-0.95279992]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, however it doesn't work over the whole range.  It gives no solutions for `0 < y <= 0.205`, one solution for `0.205 < y <= 0.275` and two solutions for `0.275 < y < max(y)`.  Eyeballing the original function shows that the inverse should have two values for every value `0 < y < max(y)`.  These ranges are approximate and for `m = 0.5` and `n = 0.5`.

Comment: Yeah that is likely to happen. The best solution then is to subdivide the domain into 10-20 sub-domains and with an initial guess at the centre of each sub-domain `newton_krylov` can be called.